# Trackpad not working after adjusting after-typing delay

Tags: touchpad

I just typed in the following command to reduce the trackpad delay after typing:

```
syndaemon -i 0.5 -d
```

The trackpad is now completely unresponsive. Luckily this Lenovo has a Touchpoint. I can still right- and left-click on the trackpad. How can I revert the above command?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I managed to revert it back after restarting but now the delay is back.